# Problem with execute aristan from Laravel in Docker

Tags: laravel, docker, composer-php, laradock

I have installed:
https://laradock.io

When I run this command:

```
docker-compose exec --user=laradock workspace bash php project1/artisan preset none
```

I have error:

```
/usr/bin/php: /usr/bin/php: cannot execute binary file
```

My file/folder structure:
- laradock
- project1/public

How can I can run this command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove "bash" from your command.

Run this:

```sh
docker-compose exec --user=laradock workspace php project1/artisan preset none
```